# How can a scythe be used for mass assassinations?

Tags: weapons, combat

I want a scythe to be used for a mass murder, far-range combat, & close-range combat, and I need it to be large to create fear in opponents.
Although the massive scythes shown in anime can be destructive, I think they're hard to use in tight places and hallways. I thought about making both sides of the blade sharp but the impracticality of the distance between the handle and the blade itself is still unsolved. 
I need a way in which it's practical but I can still keep the size. The unbalanced weight is not an issue.

Comment: It can't, for the same reason that a scimitar can't, or and other melee weapon.

Comment: Hi @ER22, welcome to World Building. Are you talking about a normal agricultural scythe or a [war scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe)? I'm not sure a traditional scythe would make a particular great weapon (other than of necessity), it seems that when used in battle they were usually remade to move the blade to a better position for combat. Which shape were you thinking of?

Comment: Ever used a scythe?  (I mean the agricultural sort, not the above-mentioned war scythe.) It's designed to swing so that you cut things near ground level.  It would be quite awkward to use to kill someone, unless by cutting their feet off and hoping they bleed to death.  If you wanted a weapon, you would do far better to unbolt the blade from the snathe https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snath and make a short handle parallel to the blade, turning it into a fairly effective sword.

Comment: Does the blade itself have to do the killing, or could you do something like put a gun inside it?

Comment: Hi ER22, welcome to worldbuilding.SE!  I'd like to point out that no melee weapon can be used for "far-range combat" and "I need it to be large" is a contradiction of "use in tight places and hallways."  Adding something (like pneumatically throwing the blade) means it's no longer a scythe and you'd need magic to overcome the second problem.  May I suggest you delete this question and re-ask it in our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) so you can refine the question?

Comment: Actually, what do you consider mass-murder? How high the count kill has to be? Is this a sort of magical weapon, one-of-its-kind, or is it used regularly by an army of sorts?

Comment: A scythe is surprisingly fragile. With some modifications they can be used in combat, but I suspect the thing will break long before you can be considered a mass murderer. If you make enough modifications to make it more practical, I suspect you just end up at other pole weapons ...

Comment: Explain my man or lady, what kind of world is this? What are the limits, is their magic, is he a murderer is he a magic guy or is this the future, past, present? Whats the limits on what we can and cannot do with this scythe of yours.

Comment: For fighting in close quarters, give it a telescoping handle. For far-range killing, either it telescopes out ridiculously far, or it shoots its blade, or maybe even fires a bunch of mini-scythes. Any of these would be perfectly reasonable as a villain for Ranma or 60s Batman to fight; not so much for a "down-to-earth" Nolan Batman story or a "dark & gritty" Miller Batman—but that's why you have to tell us what kind of world you're trying to build.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to refine this question.  In particular, "scythe" is a very specific noun, and the thing that a scythe is is terrible for your uses.  We're going to have to deconstruct the scythe a bit to make something remotely effective, and it'd be good to know which properties of the scythe are important to keep and which ones can be torn down and built up differently.

Comment: "Assassination", "Murder" and "Combat" seem to be used as synonyms in the question, but have quite distinct meanings.  "Mass-assassination" is almost a contradiction.  Refining the question would is highly desirable.

Comment: To paraphrase Pratchett: “The pitchforks are good, and the torches go without saying, but the scythes... No no, Not a good mob weapon, believe me. A simple sickle is much better. Start waving scythes around and someone is going to lose an eye.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, long range and short range capability isn't very feasible in one multipurpose weapon, but why not carry multiples? Without any context regarding magic, technological advancement or historical accuracy, I decided to stick to a more reality-based answer and included a quick sketch to illustrate my point.

[image: Sketch of scythe concept]

Use a large, impressive scythe as your signature weapon. It's big, it's scary, it cuts through small groups of bunched up enemies like so many blades of grass. But make it foldable (see pic, item C). A two-part handle and the blade folds down in line. Have it fold outward against the direction of swing so it won't do any inconvenient fold-up when you slice, plus you get to pull off cinematic all-in-one unfold and slice manoeuvres. Strap to back when not in use.

For tight corridors, pack a couple of sickle-sized single handed scythes (picture, A and B) to weave through enemies at close range and for quiet assassinations. If weighted correctly, these can be thrown like tomahawks to kill at range, or for a less practical but impressive looking weapon, connected with a quick locking mechanism to make a large whirling shuriken of death.

Answer (score 6):

**The scythe can be moved in 4 dimensions.**

If you can move the scythe *kata* and *ana*, you can move it entirely into an adjacent 3D plane and out of ours.  You can move as much of it back into our 3d plane as you see fit.

For close quarters you might just have 5 inches of the blade, apparently protruding from your palm.  Or you can shift the whole thing into plane, swing it, shift it back out of plane to miss an obstacle, and back into plane to intercept your target.

An interesting aspect is what the entirety of the scythe actually looks like.  Maybe it is just a bigass scythe.  But there may be more to it than that.  Its 4d form might be something very different.

How exactly you swing a thing in the *kata* direction is left as an exercise for the writer.  I am sure it takes practice.

Comment: Some argue that the fourth dimension is time: so basically, time travel :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no middle-aged weapon that is going to be good in all situations. If you want far-range combat, you sacrifice closer range combat and if you want close range combat you sacrifice far range combat.

The entire concept of a farming scythe used as a weapon is flawed. As you mentioned yourself, its a large weapon with an extremely small attack range. Its basically saying, I can kill you if your close to me and You can kill me if your close to me at the same time. Anime, Mangas and Cartoons greatly exaggerate the effect of any weapon because they aren't about the plausibility, but more into the coolness factor.

If you do want to use it for mass murder, I would suggest not using a single physical scythe, but throwing the scythe or shooting it. You get your long range. For close range, just pull out another scythe or have the thrown scythe defy physics and return to you after cutting 10 people apart and hitting a wall.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the scythe blade s-shaped, with the handle attache to the center of the 's' curve. Sharpen the inside curve on the inside, and sharpen the outside curve on the outside. The inside curve is for close contact, and the outside blade is for more distant combat.

Answer (score 0):

Mass killings? Sounds like you either need a big scythe or tons of smaller ones. For the manipulation of many small scythes you could have some sort of telekenesis army of Psions. They could even control tiny scythes which they can conjour in the brains of their enemys to quickly rupture key brain components.

Going the big route perhaps they used hand scythes as a throwing weapon but then adapted them into a ballistic weapon of massive scale. Sort of like a trebuchet but it creates rotational energy flinging the scythe in a circular path of death.

Why just one? Have the guy be able to hurl large ones with his mind and conjure spirint scythes to extinguish key components of an enemy. Could lead to interesting moves.